# Set root directory on shared hosting for multiple projects

Tags: apache, server, shared-hosting

Locally, I can change the root directory of apache following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891802/how-do-i-change-the-root-directory-of-an-apache-server). What I really want is to set up a way to have multiple projects with a different root directory for each project. I did this with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244878/how-to-run-multiple-projects-on-apache-using-virtual-hosts).

I have a shared hosting plan (Apache running on Linux Ubuntu) where I would like to test these projects in a more production-like environment. The problem I run into, is that I cannot configure a different root directory for each project because I cannot configure Apache on this shared hosting.

My question is, is there any way to 'tell' Apache I have different projects with different document roots? I'm hoping there is a solution like having a .htaccess file per project with this setting, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of "it depends", so I will address the most common setups.

1) How do you define "multiple projects"?  Usually that means 1 project == 1 domain.

- Your provider should allow you to setup multiple domains on your web space.  Each domain is then linked to 1 directory in your web space.  This incurs fees, to pay for each domain.
- Ex. for 1and1 (not a publicity, it just happens have a sites on their setup):  www.example1.com points to /example1, www.example2.com points to /example2, and so on.  This is setup in their administration interface.
- Doing it like this is equivalent to setting up multiple `VirtualHost` sections.

2) 1 project == 1 domain prefix

- Depending how your hoster does it, you could setup prefix1.example.com points to /site1 and prefix2.example.com points to /site2.
- The user never sees /site1 or /site2 in their address bar.
- Again that is done in the administration interface of your provider.

3) 1 project == 1 sub-directory of one domain, you cannot edit .htaccess

- If you do not mind that, each project could be a sub-directory to the 1 domain you have.
- www.example.com/project1, www.example.com/project2, ...
- The user of your site must type in www.example.com/projectX to get access to the project.  It is not hidden in the configuration, the user must explicitly input the project he wants in the browser address bar.
- This does not require any configuration in Apache, or at the hoster level.  Simply put the different directories under the `DocumentRoot` directory of the entire domain.
- This does not provide a "clean" separation of the sites, but it might be enough for your needs.

4) like 3), but you can edit .htaccess files

- In the `DocumentRoot` directory create a .htaccess file
- In there, use `Alias` to tell Apache that requests to a sub-directory in the URL corresponds to another directory on disk, somewhere OTHER than under `DocumentRoot` like in 3)
- This scenario might be less probable since your hoster will probably only allow you to put content under the `DocumentRoot` anyway.
- See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Have fun!